# Segmentation fault in double pendulum code by Runge-Kutta

Tags: fortran, numerical-methods, runge-kutta

I'm trying to numerically solve the double pendulum by Runge-Kutta fourth order.

The differential equations to be solved are on the following page:

http://www.myphysicslab.com/dbl_pendulum.html

There is even an animation showing the angles 1 and 2. I want to solve the equations that appear further down the page by Runge-Kutta method.

Print these results to a file and then plot them using gnuplot. But, my program does not run and can not find the reason, I hope you can help me.

My code in Fortran:

```
PROGRAM MAIN

!In this program the double pendulum is solved by Rugen-Kutta method of order 4

!variables required
INTEGER, PARAMETER:: PREC = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(9,99)
REAL(PREC), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: theta1, theta2, omega1, omega2, t
REAL(PREC) :: LEN1, LEN2, M1, M2, G, PI, DT
!The following variables are for the Runge-Kutta
REAL(PREC) :: K11, K12, K13, K14, K21, K22, K23, K24
REAL(PREC) :: K31, K32, K33, K34, K41, K42, K43, K44
INTEGER :: I, J, N

!Definition of variables needed
PI= 4.*ATAN(1.)
I=0
G=9.8
DT=0.0003 !change over time
T(0)= 0.0 !initial time

!number of repetitions
n=500000
ALLOCATE (theta1(0:n),omega1(0:n),theta2(0:n),omega2(0:n),t(0:n))

!Initials values are given by the user
PRINT*, 'First pendulum'
CALL INICIALIZA(THETA1, OMEGA1, N, LEN1, M1)
PRINT*, ' '
PRINT*, 'Second pendulum'
CALL INICIALIZA(THETA2, OMEGA2, N, LEN2, M2)

!Runge-kutta method
DO

!Runge-Kutta fourth order
    !
    K11 = DT*OMEGA1(I)
    K21 = DT*OMEGA2(I)
    K31 = DT*DOM1(M1, M2, THETA1(I), THETA2(I) & 
    , OMEGA1(I), OMEGA2(I), LEN1, LEN2, G)
    K41 = DT*DOM2(M1, M2, THETA1(I), THETA2(I) & 
    , OMEGA1(I), OMEGA2(I), LEN1, LEN2, G)
    !
    K12 = DT*(OMEGA1(I) + K11/2.0)
    K22 = DT*(OMEGA2(I) + K21/2.0)
    K32 = DT*DOM1(M1, M2, (THETA1(I) + K11/2.0), (THETA2(I) + K21/2.0) & 
    , (OMEGA1(I) + K31/2.0), (OMEGA2(I) + K41/2.0), LEN1, LEN2, G)
    K42 = DT*DOM2(M1, M2, (THETA1(I) + K11/2.0), (THETA2(I) + K21/2.0) & 
    , (OMEGA1(I) + K31/2.0), (OMEGA2(I) + K41/2.0), LEN1, LEN2, G)
    !
    K13 = DT*(OMEGA1(I) + K12/2.0)
    K23 = DT*(OMEGA1(I) + K22/2.0)
    K33 = DT*DOM1(M1, M2, (THETA1(I) + K12/2.0), (THETA2(I) + K22/2.0) & 
    , (OMEGA1(I) + K32/2.0), (OMEGA2(I) + K42/2.0), LEN1, LEN2, G)
    K43 = DT*DOM2(M1, M2, (THETA1(I) + K12/2.0), (THETA2(I) + K22/2.0) & 
    , (OMEGA1(I) + K32/2.0), (OMEGA2(I) + K42/2.0), LEN1, LEN2, G)
    !
    K14 = DT*(OMEGA1(I) + K13)
    K24 = DT*(OMEGA1(I) + K23)
    K34 = DT*DOM1(M1, M2, (THETA1(I) + K13), (THETA2(I) + K23) & 
    , (OMEGA1(I) + K33), (OMEGA2(I) + K43), LEN1, LEN2, G)
    K44 = DT*DOM2(M1, M2, (THETA1(I) + K13), (THETA2(I) + K23) & 
    , (OMEGA1(I) + K33), (OMEGA2(I) + K43), LEN1, LEN2, G)
    !
    THETA1(I+1) = THETA1(I)+((K11+(2.0*(K12+K13))+K14)/6.0)
    THETA2(I+1) = THETA2(I)+((K21+(2.0*(K22+K23))+K24)/6.0)
    OMEGA1(I+1) = OMEGA1(I)+((K31+(2.0*(K32+K33))+K34)/6.0)
    OMEGA2(I+1) = OMEGA2(I)+((K41+(2.0*(K42+K43))+K44)/6.0)
    !
    if (theta1(i+1) > PI ) theta1(i+1)=theta1(i+1)-2.*PI
    if (theta1(i+1) < -PI) theta1(i+1)=theta1(i+1)+2.*PI
    if (theta2(i+1) > PI ) theta2(i+1)=theta2(i+1)-2.*PI
    if (theta2(i+1) < -PI) theta2(i+1)=theta2(i+1)+2.*PI    

    t(i+1) = t(i) + dt

    IF (i >= n-1) EXIT

    i=i+1

ENDDO
!The results are saved in a file
OPEN (UNIT=10,FILE='dou2.dat',STATUS='UNKNOWN')

do j=0,n
    wRITE(10,*) theta1(j),theta2(j),omega1(j),omega2(j),t(j)
end do

CLOSE(10)

END PROGRAM MAIN

!Subroutine to initial values
SUBROUTINE inicializa(theta, omega, n ,length, m)
INTEGER, PARAMETER:: PREC = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(9,99)
INTEGER, INTENT (IN):: n
REAL(PREC), DIMENSION(0:n):: theta, omega
REAL(PREC):: length, m
print*,'starting angle'
read*, theta(0)
print*,'Initial angular velocity'
read*, omega(0)
print*,'Lenght of pendulum'
read*, length
print*, 'Mass pendulum'
read*, m
END SUBROUTINE inicializa

!Functions that determine the derivative of omega (the angular velocity)

REAL FUNCTION DOM1(N1, N2, X1, X2, Y1, Y2, L1, L2, A)
    INTEGER, PARAMETER:: PREC = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(9,99)
    REAL(PREC) :: N1, N2, X1, X2, Y1, Y2, L1, L2, A
    DOM1 = ((-A*((2.0*N1)+N2)*SIN(X1))-(N2*A*SIN(X1-(2.0*X2))) & 
    -(2.0*SIN(X1-X2)*N2*((Y2*Y2*L2)+(Y1*Y1*L1*COS(X1-X2))))) &
    /(L1*((2.0*N1)+N2-(N2*COS((2.0*X1)-(2.0*X2)))))
END FUNCTION DOM1

REAL FUNCTION DOM2(N1, N2, X1, X2, Y1, Y2, L1, L2, A)
    INTEGER, PARAMETER:: PREC = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(9,99)
    REAL(PREC) :: N1, N2, X1, X2, Y1, Y2, L1, L2, A
    DOM2 = (2.0*SIN(X1-X2)*((Y1*Y1*L1*(N1+N2))+(A*(N1+N2)*COS(X1)) &
    +(Y2*Y2*L2*N2*COS(X1-X2))))/(L2*((2.0*N1)+N2 &
    -N2*COS((2.0*X1)-(2.0*X2))))
END FUNCTION DOM2
```

Here is a good description of the method: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Runge-KuttaMethod.html

The error that I get when running the program is:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
Backtrace for this error:
   #0  0xB763D163
   #1  0xB763D800
   #2  0xB774A3FF
   #3  0x8048F17 in MAIN__ at doupend2.f90:?
 Violación de segmento
```

Comment: You should compile your code for debugging. If you use gfortran, use `-g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall`. For ifort use `-g -traceback-check -warn`. Other compilers have similar options.

Comment: Most probably it is some wrong array indexing.

Comment: You didn't allocate 't', when you did T(0) = 0.0, which is probably giving the segfault

Comment: As Vladimir has mentioned, get in the habit of doing a thorough compile like `gfortran -g -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra -O2`. This reveals things like `Possible change of value in conversion from REAL(8) to REAL(4)` at `DOM1 = ((-A*((2.0*N1)+N2)*SIN(X1))-(N2*A*SIN(X1-(2.0*X2))) &` for `DOM1`. Fix this by specifying double precision for `DOM1` like so: `REAL(PREC) FUNCTION DOM1(N1, N2, X1, X2, Y1, Y2, L1, L2, A)`. Put `PREC` in a `module` and import that declaration with `USE [module name], ONLY : PREC` in function `DOM1`. Comment out the redundant `INTEGER` declaration. Also take care of `DOM2`.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanical problem of the double pendulum and numerical integration of the initial value of motion equations via the 4th order numerical method of Runge-Kutta. The chosen language was FORTRAN together with the gfortran compiler. The graphs were generated in gnuplot.

```
!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!
!         FEDERAL UNIVERSITY OF GOIÁS (UFG)         !
!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!
! Author            : VY Canis Majoris              !
! Theme             : Double Pendulum               !
! Language          : Fortran 90                    !
! Compiler          : Gfortran                      !
! Operating System  : Windows 10                    !
! Creation date     : 02/05/2023                    !
! Modification Date : 02/13/2023                    !
!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!
!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!

program Pendulo_Duplo
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: n = 100000
    real               :: h = 1.0E-3
    real               :: t0,o1_0,o2_0,w1_0,w2_0,m1,m2,l1,l2,g, eps
    real               :: t(n),o1(n),o2(n),w1(n),w2(n)! saída
    real               :: theta1(n),theta2(n),wtheta1(n),wtheta2(n)! saída
    

    !%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!
    !  Enter the double pendulum attributes and initial conditions !
    !%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!
      t0 = 00.000
    o1_0 = -45.000
    o2_0 = 45.000
    w1_0 = 00.000
    w2_0 = 00.000
      m1 = 01.000
      m2 = 01.000
      l1 = 01.000
      l2 = 01.000
       g = 09.810


    call RK4(t0,o1_0,o2_0,w1_0,w2_0,h,n,m1,m2,l1,l2,g,t,o1,o2,w1,w2)

    stop
end program Pendulo_Duplo

!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!
! Differential equations of the double pendulum !
!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!

! FIRST ODE
real function f1(t, o1, o2, w1, w2)
    implicit none
    real, intent(in) :: t, o1, o2, w1, w2
    f1 = w1
end function f1

! SECOND ODE
real function f2(t, o1, o2, w1, w2)
    implicit none
    real, intent(in) :: t, o1, o2, w1, w2
    f2 = w2
end function f2

! THIRD ODE
real function f3(t, o1, o2, w1, w2, m1, m2, l1, l2, g)
    implicit none
    real, intent(in) :: t, o1, o2, w1, w2
    real, intent(in) :: m1, m2, l1, l2, g

    f3 = (-G * (2 * M1 + M2) * sin(o1)&
                - M2 * G * sin(o1 - 2 * o2)&
                - 2 * sin(o1 - o2) * M2 * ((w2**2) * L2&
                + (w1**2) * L1 * cos(o1 - o2))) / (L1 * (2 * M1 + M2&
                - M2 * cos(2 * o1 - 2 * o2)))
end function f3

! FOURTH ODE
real function f4(t, o1, o2, w1, w2, m1, m2, l1, l2, g)
    implicit none
    real, intent(in) :: t, o1, o2, w1, w2
    real, intent(in) :: m1, m2, l1, l2, g

    f4 = (2 * sin(o1 - o2) * ((w1**2) * L1 * (M1&
                + M2) + G * (M1 + M2) * cos(o1)&
                + (w2**2) * L2 * M2 * cos(o1 - o2))) / (L2 * (2 * M1&
                + M2 - M2 * cos(2 * o1 - 2 * o2)))
end function f4

! CHANGE FUNCTION FROM DEGREES TO RADIANS
real function radianos(graus)
    implicit none
    real :: graus
    real(Kind = 8) :: pi
    pi = 4.0*atan(1.0d0)
    radianos = (pi/180)*graus
end function radianos

!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!
!  Sub Routine for the 4 Order Runge-Kutta method  !
!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!
subroutine RK4(t0,o1_0,o2_0,w1_0,w2_0,h,n,m1,m2,l1,l2,g,t,o1,o2,w1,w2)
    implicit none
    !%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!
    !    INPUT VARIABLES (INPUTS)   !
    !%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    real,    intent(in) :: h
    real,    intent(in) :: t0, o1_0, o2_0, w1_0, w2_0
    real,    intent(in) :: m1, m2, l1, l2, g
    !%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!
    !   RETURN VARIABLES (OUTPUTS)   !
    !%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!
    real, intent(out)   :: t(n), o1(n), o2(n), w1(n), w2(n)
    !%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!
    ! AUXILIARY VARIABLES - INTERNAL STATEMENTS !
    !%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!
    integer        :: i
    real           :: k11, k21, k31, k41
    real           :: k12, k22, k32, k42
    real           :: k13, k23, k33, k43
    real           :: k14, k24, k34, k44
    real, external ::  f1,  f2,  f3,  f4, radianos
    real           :: x1(n), x2(n), y1(n), y2(n)

    !%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!
    ! Initial conditions !
    !%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%!
     t(1) = t0
    o1(1) = radianos(o1_0)
    o2(1) = radianos(o2_0)
    w1(1) = w1_0
    w2(1) = w2_0

    do i = 1,n-1
        k11 = h*f1(t(i),o1(i),o2(i),w1(i),w2(i))
        k12 = h*f2(t(i),o1(i),o2(i),w1(i),w2(i))
        k13 = h*f3(t(i),o1(i),o2(i),w1(i),w2(i),m1,m2,l1,l2,g)
        k14 = h*f4(t(i),o1(i),o2(i),w1(i),w2(i),m1,m2,l1,l2,g)

        k21 = h*f1(t(i)+h/2,o1(i)+k11/2,o2(i)+k12/2,w1(i)+k13/2,w2(i)+k14/2)
        k22 = h*f2(t(i)+h/2,o1(i)+k11/2,o2(i)+k12/2,w1(i)+k13/2,w2(i)+k14/2)
        k23 = h*f3(t(i)+h/2,o1(i)+k11/2,o2(i)+k12/2,w1(i)+k13/2,w2(i)+k14/2,m1,m2,l1,l2,g)
        k24 = h*f4(t(i)+h/2,o1(i)+k11/2,o2(i)+k12/2,w1(i)+k13/2,w2(i)+k14/2,m1,m2,l1,l2,g)

        k31 = h*f1(t(i)+h/2,o1(i)+k21/2,o2(i)+k22/2,w1(i)+k23/2,w2(i)+k24/2)
        k32 = h*f2(t(i)+h/2,o1(i)+k21/2,o2(i)+k22/2,w1(i)+k23/2,w2(i)+k24/2)
        k33 = h*f3(t(i)+h/2,o1(i)+k21/2,o2(i)+k22/2,w1(i)+k23/2,w2(i)+k24/2,m1,m2,l1,l2,g)
        k34 = h*f4(t(i)+h/2,o1(i)+k21/2,o2(i)+k22/2,w1(i)+k23/2,w2(i)+k24/2,m1,m2,l1,l2,g)

        k41 = h*f1(t(i)+h,o1(i)+k31,o2(i)+k32,w1(i)+k33,w2(i)+k34)
        k42 = h*f2(t(i)+h,o1(i)+k31,o2(i)+k32,w1(i)+k33,w2(i)+k34)
        k43 = h*f3(t(i)+h,o1(i)+k31,o2(i)+k32,w1(i)+k33,w2(i)+k34,m1,m2,l1,l2,g)
        k44 = h*f4(t(i)+h,o1(i)+k31,o2(i)+k32,w1(i)+k33,w2(i)+k34,m1,m2,l1,l2,g)
   
        o1(i+1) = o1(i) + ((k11+2*(k21+k31)+k41)/6)
        o2(i+1) = o2(i) + ((k12+2*(k22+k32)+k42)/6)
        w1(i+1) = w1(i) + ((k13+2*(k23+k33)+k43)/6)
        w2(i+1) = w2(i) + ((k14+2*(k24+k34)+k44)/6)
         t(i+1) =  t(i) + h

        !write(*,*) t(i),o1(i),o2(i),w1(i),w2(i)
    end do

    ! Generation of .dat files !
    open(0,file = "pd0.dat")
        open(1,file = "pd1.dat")
            do i = 1,n-1
                
                ! Position of mass m1 in the xy plane !
                x1(i) =  l1*sin(o1(i))
                y1(i) = -l1*cos(o1(i))

                ! Position of mass m2 in the xy plane !
                x2(i) =  l1*sin(o1(i))+l2*sin(o2(i))
                y2(i) = -l1*cos(o1(i))-l2*cos(o2(i))

                !write(*,*) x1(i),y1(i),x2(i),y2(i)

                !           1    2     3     4      5      6
                write(0,*) 0.0, 0.0, x1(i), y1(i), x2(i), y2(i)
            end do

            do i = 1,n-1
                !           1      2      3     4      5
                write(1,*) t(i), o1(i), o2(i), w1(i), w2(i)
            end do
        close(1)
    close(0)

end subroutine RK4
```

The graphics were generated through .dat files with the help of gnuplot. [Figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHosR.png) is a plot of the positions of the respective masses m1 and m2 in the xy plane. [Figure2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wP9R.png) consists of the plot of the generalized coordinates (angle1 and angle 2) in the configuration space.

Comment: It os not a good idea to open files under unit 0 or even other number brlow 10. Compilers frequently use unit 0 for the standard error output and according to the standard, the unit number shall be positive.

Comment: But this post does not really answer the question asked and does not touch the errors at all. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service where a complete code for a given problem statement would be an answer.

Comment: Or said another way, this new, different code does not answer the question about where the original code went wrong. A proper answer would take up the comment about the `T` array not being defined and explore if further errors in the original code appear.